# Vowel datatype in Haskell, is it possible?

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I have written the following code to remove vowels from a sentence:

```
   main = print $ unixname "The House"

   vowel x = elem x "aeiouAEIOU"

   unixname :: [Char] -> [Char]
   unixname [] = []
   unixname (x:xs) | vowel x = unixname xs
            | otherwise = x : unixname xs
```

Just wondering if it is possible to create a data type for vowel? The compiler won't let me use characters in a data type.

Comment: I wasn't aware that vowels weren't allowed in UNIX names ;)

Comment: Why do you want a "data type for vowel"? What would it do?

Comment: @Anschel, presumably be a `Char` whose values can only take on vowels.  It would be a way to declare the one of the correctness criteria for `unixname`.  Er... actually not because he needs its complement, but you get the idea.

Comment: It's simply an exercise given in my CS course, don't know why he called it "unixname", for a function that removes vowels.

Comment: you alternatively could use `unixname = filter consonant` where `consonant = not . vowel`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not directly.  The problem is that characters are a built-in type with no facility for polymorphism.  This is different from numeric literals, which are designed to be polymorphic via the `Num` type class.

That said, there are two basic approaches you can take: a newtype wrapper with a smart constructor, or a totally new type.

The newtype wrapper is easier to use:

```
module Vowel (Vowel, vowel, fromVowel) where

newtype Vowel = Vowel Char

vowel :: Char -> Maybe (Vowel)
vowel x | x `elem` "aeiouAEIOU" = Just (Vowel x)
        | otherwise = Nothing

fromVowel :: Vowel -> Char
fromVowel (Vowel x) = x
```

Since the `Vowel` constructor isn't exported, new `Vowel`s can only be created by the `vowel` function, which only admits the characters you want.

You could also make a new type like this:

```
data Vowel = A | E | I | O | U | Aa | Ee | Ii | Oo | Uu

fromChar :: Char -> Maybe Vowel
fromChar 'a' = Just Aa
fromChar 'A' = Just A
-- etc.

toChar :: Vowel -> Char
toChar Aa = 'a'
toChar A = 'A'
```

This second way is pretty heavyweight, and therefore is much more awkward to use.

So that's how to do it.  I'm not quite certain that you want to though.  The usual idiom is to make types that represent your data, and you specifically **don't** represent vowels.  A common pattern would be something like this:

```
newtype CleanString = Cleaned { raw :: String }

-- user input needs to be sanitized
cleanString :: String -> CleanString
```

Here the newtype differentiates between unsanitized and sanitized input.  If the only way to make a `CleanString` is by `cleanString`, then you know statically that every `CleanString` is properly sanitized (provided that `cleanString` is correct).  In your case, it seems you actually need a type for consonants, not vowels.

Newtypes in Haskell are very lightweight*, but the programmer does have to write and use code to do the wrapping and unwrapping.  In many instances the benefits outweigh the extra work.  However, I really can't think of any application where it's important to know that your `String` is vowel-free, so I'd probably just work with a plain `String`.

*newtypes only exist at compile-time, so in theory there's no runtime performance cost to using them.  However, their existence can change the produced code (e.g. inhibiting RULEs), so sometimes there is a measurable performance impact.

Answer (score 8):

You could use [phantom types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Phantom_type) to tag characters with extra information, in order to make the type system guarantee during compile time that your strings only contain, for example, vowels or non-vowels.

Here's a toy example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}

import Data.Maybe

newtype TaggedChar a = TaggedChar { fromTaggedChar :: Char }

data Vowel
data NonVowel

isVowel x = x `elem` "aeiouyAEIOUY"

toVowel :: Char -> Maybe (TaggedChar Vowel)
toVowel x
    | isVowel x = Just $ TaggedChar x
    | otherwise = Nothing

toNonVowel :: Char -> Maybe (TaggedChar NonVowel)
toNonVowel x
    | isVowel x = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just $ TaggedChar x

unixname :: [Char] -> [TaggedChar NonVowel]
unixname = mapMaybe toNonVowel
```

The benefit of this approach is that you can still also write functions that work on all TaggedChars regardless of the tag. For example:

```
toString :: [TaggedChar a] -> String
toString = map fromTaggedChar
```